# Flex/Eclipse Way of saving the list of projects in a workspace

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am developing a few flex applications along with several common libraries using FlashBuilder 4.5. The applications links to the libraries. I work as part of a team. So I have a workspace into which I import all the projects (application and libraries) . Each project is in source control (git). So the workspace often has Application A, Application B,... Application X
 Library 1, Library 2, Library 3, and many more. The libraries are often used by many of the applications. So it is useful to have a workspace where all this in it at the same time.

I would like a way of storing in source control the list of projects in the workspace. So this way, the whole team has the same projects in the workspace.  The only way  I know is to save the [workspace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources
in source control - which is a bad idea for various reasons (namely 1.tree etc keep getting regenerated).

Currently if I import all the projects, because I have the libraries linked, when I open an application it correctly opens all the related projects. But I need this functionality for importing.

Is there a construct in Flex, or some better way in Eclipse that allows this?
Essentially I want to group a bunch of projects together - that I can import in one go - that has exactly what the entire team ought to have imported into their workspaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Team Project Sets to import a set of projects.

Use 'File > Export > Team > Team Project Set' to create a project set file.

Other people can than import the project set using 'File > Import > Team > Team Project Set'.

See the [Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-cvs-project-set.htm) for more details.

Comment: I just tried this, thanks. The problem now is in FlashBuilder 4.5 it does not give me any projects eligible for export. I can export each individual project as a Flash Builder project - so maybe this is just not supported for Flex?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know anything about Flex